# ipywidgets interact does not work

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I am trying `ipywidgets.interact` [hello world example](http://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Using%20Interact.html) but the expected element does not show up.

This is the code:

```
 from __future__ import print_function
 from ipywidgets import interact, interactive, fixed, interact_manual
 import ipywidgets as widgets

 def f(x):
    return x

 interact(f, x= 'test')
```

These are the session parameters:

```
CPython 2.7.14
IPython 5.6.0

ipywidgets 7.2.0

compiler   : GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)
system     : Darwin
release    : 15.6.0
machine    : x86_64
processor  : i386
CPU cores  : 4
interpreter: 64bit
```

Comment: I slightly edited the question body, to make it go straight to the point and added what I think is the most relevant tag (ipywidgets).

Comment: Maybe this question can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36351109/ipython-notebook-ipywidgets-does-not-show#38001920

Comment: The matter was Internet Explorer %)