# Zoom and Pan Options in plots for matplotlib on jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I would like to have zooming and panning options for plots generated in matplotlib on jupyter notebook. I tried installing mpld3 but importing the package doesn't generate my plots at all. Is it an issue of the version of Anaconda I'm using (Anaconda2)? What should I do to fix it? Any help is appreciated, Thank You

Comment: Try run magic command `%matplotlib notebook` prior to the plot.

Comment: For zooming and panning you need an interactive backend. Often the default settings of IPython/jupyter notebook are to show a png image of the plot; pngs are not interactive. You may use e.g. `%matplotlib qt`,  `%matplotlib notebook`, `%matplotlib ipympl`.

Answer (score 0):

for me, the following worked:

1. install ipympl, the backend for matplotlib to draw, is interactive: `pip install ipympl` or `conda install ipympl` ([ipympl install in jupyter-notebook (python3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55729136/))
2. install ipywidgets, the jupyter stuff ipympl needs to draw: `pip install ipywidgets` or `conda install ipywidgets`  ([IPython Notebook ipywidgets does not show](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36351109))
3. use the matplotlib magic: `%matplotlib ipympl`

related other questions:

- [jupyterlab interactive plot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50149562/7431523)
- [Matplotlib magic in Jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61625435))

Answer (score 0):

For me ipympl didn't work, but this magic did helped:

```
%matplotlib notebook
```

[image]

Found at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=meR8ehNxAK4