# ipympl install in jupyter-notebook (python3)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, python-3.7

Greeting. I have an issue installing the ipympl module to my jupyter-notebook path. If I pip install it it says that I installed it for python2.7 (and I obviously want it for python3). now I also cannot conda install it since my conda prompt is not working. I am at a loss

Answer (score 8):

If you have Anaconda installed on your system, then you can use the following comand:

```
conda install -c conda-forge ipympl
```

Answer (score 8):

Just install ipyml, you don't need extra actions.

```
pip install ipympl
```