# Jupyter Notebook not rendering ipywidgets

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

Instead of rendering the actual widgets, it's just rendering text labels. See screenshot below.

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display

label = widgets.Label(value='Hello!')

display(label)
>>> Label(value='Hello!')
```

[image]

## Edit

The above works for me on my local computer, but not on a server. Both are running Python 3.6, `jupyter-core==4.6.3`

## Edit 2

In response to the question by @adhg, here's the output of `widgets.InsSlider()` (in his question, (s)he had a typo `Ins` instead of `Int`)

[image]

Comment: This code works for me (with a Python 3 notebook).

Comment: what do you get when you run this: import ipywidgets as widgets and then widgets.InsSlider() ?

Comment: See "edit 2". I've never seen this before where ipywidgets just render that instead of the widgets...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36351109/ipython-notebook-ipywidgets-does-not-show):

> With the new version of ipywidgets, I ran into this problem, but then I found on [their github readme](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/blob/master/README.md) that you now need to follow

```
pip install ipywidgets
```

> with

```
jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
```