# Ipywidgets (Vbox) not showing up on Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly, ipywidgets

I am running into this error

```
A Jupyter widget could not be displayed because the widget state could not be found. This could happen if the kernel storing the widget is no longer available, or if the widget state was not saved in the notebook. You may be able to create the widget by running the appropriate cells.
```

When I run:

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.offline as py

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from ipywidgets import interactive, HBox, VBox

py.init_notebook_mode()

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jonmmease/plotly_ipywidget_notebooks/master/notebooks/data/cars/cars.csv')

f = go.FigureWidget([go.Scatter(y = df['City mpg'], x = df['City mpg'], mode = 'markers')])
scatter = f.data[0]
N = len(df)
scatter.x = scatter.x + np.random.rand(N)/10 *(df['City mpg'].max() - df['City mpg'].min())
scatter.y = scatter.y + np.random.rand(N)/10 *(df['City mpg'].max() - df['City mpg'].min())
scatter.marker.opacity = 0.5

def update_axes(xaxis, yaxis):
    scatter = f.data[0]
    scatter.x = df[xaxis]
    scatter.y = df[yaxis]
    with f.batch_update():
        f.layout.xaxis.title = xaxis
        f.layout.yaxis.title = yaxis
        scatter.x = scatter.x + np.random.rand(N)/10 *(df[xaxis].max() - df[xaxis].min())
        scatter.y = scatter.y + np.random.rand(N)/10 *(df[yaxis].max() - df[yaxis].min())

axis_dropdowns = interactive(update_axes, yaxis = df.select_dtypes('int64').columns, xaxis = df.select_dtypes('int64').columns)

# Create a table FigureWidget that updates on selection from points in the scatter plot of f
t = go.FigureWidget([go.Table(
    header=dict(values=['ID','Classification','Driveline','Hybrid'],
                fill = dict(color='#C2D4FF'),
                align = ['left'] * 5),
    cells=dict(values=[df[col] for col in ['ID','Classification','Driveline','Hybrid']],
               fill = dict(color='#F5F8FF'),
               align = ['left'] * 5))])

def selection_fn(trace,points,selector):
    t.data[0].cells.values = [df.loc[points.point_inds][col] for col in ['ID','Classification','Driveline','Hybrid']]

scatter.on_selection(selection_fn)

# Put everything together
VBox((HBox(axis_dropdowns.children),f,t))
```

`f` and `t` only show when i run `f.show()` and `t.show()`

yet when I run:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display

button = widgets.Button(description='Hello')
display(button)
```

The widget shows up fine. I have read the solutions online and tried:

```
jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
```

and

```
jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager
```

and when I check:

```
jupyter nbextension list
```

It all seems fine:

```
Known nbextensions:
  config dir: /home/hajar/.jupyter/nbconfig
    notebook section
      jupyter-js-widgets/extension  enabled 
      - Validating: OK
  config dir: /usr/local/etc/jupyter/nbconfig
    notebook section
      jupyter-js-widgets/extension  enabled 
      - Validating: OK
    tree section
      ipyparallel/main  enabled 
      - Validating: problems found:
        - require?  X ipyparallel/main
  config dir: /etc/jupyter/nbconfig
    notebook section
      jupyter-js-widgets/extension  enabled 
      - Validating: OK
```

So I am a little confused as to why its not showing the results from Vbox.
I am using Jupyter notebook.

Version list:

```
jupyter core     : 4.6.3
jupyter-notebook : 6.0.3
qtconsole        : 5.0.1
ipython          : 7.13.0
ipykernel        : 5.2.0
jupyter client   : 6.1.2
jupyter lab      : 3.0.9
nbconvert        : 5.6.1
ipywidgets       : 7.0.0
nbformat         : 5.0.4
traitlets        : 4.3.3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved- `plotlywidgets` used to render FigureWidget was not installed correctly.

I used `jupyter nbextension install --py plotlywidget --user`
and then `jupyter nbextension enable plotlywidget --user --py`

Comment: The plotlywidgt extension is only for older plotly versions (such as version 4.14.3).  It is gone for newer plotly versions (such as version 5.x).

Answer (score 0):

It is not a problem of `plotly` or `VBox`, but `ipywidgets` in general.
As explained in [IPython Notebook ipywidgets does not show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36351109/ipython-notebook-ipywidgets-does-not-show)

```
   jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
```

and restarting the Jupyter solved the problem for me.

Whether it's working, you may test with this short example

```
from ipywidgets import Button, VBox
VBox([Button(description='button 1')])
```

[image]