# Visual Studio Code does not render ipywidgets correctly

Tags: visual-studio-code, ipywidgets

I am having issue using Visual Studio Code.  the code seem to have issue with ipywidgets.
the code is below (very simple interactive chart)

```
from ipywidgets import interact
import ipywidgets as widgets
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
@interact
def foo(beta=(-10,10,1)):
    myx = np.arange(0,100,1)
    myy = myx *beta 
    print ('debug:',myy)
    fig = go.FigureWidget()
    fig.add_scatter(x= myx, y=myy)
    fig.show()
```

---

the same code works just as expected in Jupyter Notebook.
I dig further and it seems:

"widgets require us to download supporting files from a 3rd party website. Error loading plotlywidget: ^4.14.3

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/wiki/IPyWidget-Support-in-VS-Code-Python

This is where I got stuck.. What's the next then to fix this issue?

any guidance much appreciated

thanks

Comment: I added this to settings.json to no avail "jupyter.widgetScriptSources": [ "jsdelivr.com", "unpkg.com"]

Comment: @AlbertoMQ did that also, and I am still stuck ;-) (even after restarting everything obviously)

Answer (score 17):

Some of the issues I've seen reported seem to have started after the release of ipywidgets 8.

I don't understand exactly what's broken (or if it's broken), but downgrading to version `7.7.1` fixed all issues I was having.

If you want to try it as well, you can run: `pip install -U ipywidgets==7.7.1`

Comment: Great thanks this fixed my issues. Github issue here https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/8552

Answer (score -1):

There two things you can explore.

1. Check modules:

Run the `jupyter --version` command inside your conda or virtual environment.
You should see something like this:

```
IPython          : 8.4.0
ipykernel        : 6.9.1
ipywidgets       : 7.7.1
jupyter_client   : 7.2.2
jupyter_core     : 4.10.0
jupyter_server   : 1.21.0
jupyterlab       : 3.4.8
nbclient         : 0.6.4
nbconvert        : 6.5.0
nbformat         : 5.4.0
notebook         : 6.4.12
qtconsole        : not installed
traitlets        : 5.4.0
```

If there are any of those modules not installed (Apart from qtconsole) try installing them (with `pip install "module"`) and restarting the kernel.

2. Check Jupyter nbextension.

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36351109/ipython-notebook-ipywidgets-does-not-show) after running `pip install ipywidgets` try:

```
jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
```

Note: If you are using virtual environments (including conda environments) the recommended way to activate the extension is to run

```
jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix widgetsnbextension
```

I hope this helps.